# How to instruct WP not to analyze dead or unreachable code

Tags: frama-c

When running the command `frama-c test.c -rte -eva -eva-slevel 1 then -wp` on the following piece of code, I got the following results :

- Frama-c 24 : No errors
- Frama-c 25/26 : Overflows in the unreachable and dead `test` function

```
int test(int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}

int main(void)
{
  return 0
}
```

Since version 25, it looks like WP is trying to prove all annotations added by the RTE plugin, even in dead or unreachable code.
I have not found any WP options to *unselect* unreachable properties.

Is there a way to tell WP not to select dead or unreachable properties ?

Comment: Currently this is not possible out of the box. However, one question: why do you call RTE before calling Eva? This is generally less efficient, in particular because it pollutes WP proof contexts. Running Eva alone (without RTE) allows generating alarms only in the code that is alive. WP will warn saying that RTE guards have not been generated, but it is OK in a verification process, since we know that Eva has generated all necessary alarms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't sure about rte usage. What is this plugin usage ?
Removing this plugin solves the problem, but I have to add several annotations manually. Some of them (previously generated by RTE) are required by WP to succeed.

Comment: Basically: if you do not want to work with Eva, use RTE to generate all annotations and then work with WP. If you first use Eva, do not use RTE before. However, while most annotations that would be generated by RTE are not necessary to finish the proof, it happens that some of them might be useful. In this case, they are generally added by hand because it allows adding only what's necessary. There are ideas to provide information from Eva to WP on need but it is not available currently.

Answer (score 0):

## WP Goal Selection

The simple way from the command line is to use `-wp-fct` or `-wp-skip-fct` rather than just `-wp`. So in your example, run either of the following (I removed the `-rte` before `-eva` and put it with the WP call):

```
frama-c test.c -eva -eva-slevel 1 -then -wp-rte -wp -wp-fct main
frama-c test.c -eva -eva-slevel 1 -then -wp-rte -wp -wp-skip-fct test
```

Per the documentation:

- `-wp` generates proof obligations for all (selected) properties.
- `-wp-fct <f1 ,...,fn >` selects annotations of functions `f1 ,...,fn` (defaults to all functions).
- `-wp-skip-fct <f1 ,...,fn >` ignores functions `f1 ,...,fn` (defaults to none).